# Replicate Postgres pg_trgm text similarity scores in R?

Tags: r, postgresql, text, similarity, text-mining

Does anyone know how to replicate the (pg_trgm) postgres trigram similarity score from the similarity(text, text) function in R? I am using the stringdist package and would rather use R to calculate these on a matrix of text strings in a .csv file than run a bunch of postgresql quires.

Running `similarity(string1, string2)` in postgres give me a number score between 0 and 1.

I tired using the stringdist package to get a score but I think I still need to divide the code below by something.

`stringdist(string1, string2, method="qgram",q = 3 )`

Is there a way to replicate the pg_trgm score with the stringdist package or another way to do this in R?

An example would be getting the similarity score between the description of a book and the description of a genre like science fiction. For example, if I have two book descriptions and the using the similarity score of

```
book 1 = "Area X has been cut off from the rest of the continent for decades. Nature has reclaimed the last vestiges of human civilization. The first expedition returned with reports of a pristine, Edenic landscape; the second expedition ended in mass suicide, the third expedition in a hail of gunfire as its members turned on one another. The members of the eleventh expedition returned as shadows of their former selves, and within weeks, all had died of cancer. In Annihilation, the first volume of Jeff VanderMeer's Southern Reach trilogy, we join the twelfth expedition.
     The group is made up of four women: an anthropologist; a surveyor; a psychologist, the de facto leader; and our narrator, a biologist. Their mission is to map the terrain, record all observations of their surroundings and of one anotioner, and, above all, avoid being contaminated by Area X itself.
     They arrive expecting the unexpected, and Area X delivers—they discover a massive topographic anomaly and life forms that surpass understanding—but it’s the surprises that came across the border with them and the secrets the expedition members are keeping from one another that change everything."

book 2= "From Wall Street to Main Street, John Brooks, longtime contributor to the New Yorker, brings to life in vivid fashion twelve classic and timeless tales of corporate and financial life in America
     What do the $350 million Ford Motor Company disaster known as the Edsel, the fast and incredible rise of Xerox, and the unbelievable scandals at GE and Texas Gulf Sulphur have in common? Each is an example of how an iconic company was defined by a particular moment of fame or notoriety; these notable and fascinating accounts are as relevant today to understanding the intricacies of corporate life as they were when the events happened.
     Stories about Wall Street are infused with drama and adventure and reveal the machinations and volatile nature of the world of finance. John Brooks’s insightful reportage is so full of personality and critical detail that whether he is looking at the astounding market crash of 1962, the collapse of a well-known brokerage firm, or the bold attempt by American bankers to save the British pound, one gets the sense that history repeats itself.
     Five additional stories on equally fascinating subjects round out this wonderful collection that will both entertain and inform readers . . . Business Adventures is truly financial journalism at its liveliest and best."

genre 1 = "Science fiction is a genre of fiction dealing with imaginative content such as futuristic settings, futuristic science and technology, space travel, time travel, faster than light travel, parallel universes, and extraterrestrial life. It often explores the potential consequences of scientific and other innovations, and has been called a "literature of ideas".[1] Authors commonly use science fiction as a framework to explore politics, identity, desire, morality, social structure, and other literary themes."
```

How can I get a similarity score for the description of each book against the description of the science fiction genre like pg_trgm using an R script?

Comment: Can you give some example data/results so that people can attempt to replicate the results of the `pg_trgm` function?

Comment: @thelatemail It's a built-in function, see [the `pg_trgm` extension](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/pgtrgm.html). Just `CREATE EXTENSION pg_trgm`.

Comment: Nathan, do you need an *exact* match, or just "kind of similar"? If you need an exact match then unless R is using precisely the same similarity match algorithm, you'll have to either call pg_trgm from R, use the R function from Pg instead of pg_trgm, or re-impliment pg_trgm's algorithm precisely in R.

Comment: I do not need an exact match just something kind of similar. Also I don't want to pass postgresql commands to the database from R and load the pulled data back into R. Its slow and I'm terrible at sql. I know it is using trigram matching but not sure which algorithm. I am basically having that database dump all of the relevant deception data into a .csv file and using R and RStudio to calculate similarity scores and write it to a new data frame. I was hoping the stringdist package has something that will get me in the ball park of pg_tgrm.

Comment: @CraigRinger - I guessed as much, but creating a database and running a query just to get a value to check against would be a bit of overkill.

Comment: Actually its a lot of values and it won't be the whole database just a sample. Its around 50 similarity scores for each query that is currently being done by 4 different sql scripts which are over a 40 lines of code each. The scores are then being imported into R. Every time the database gets changed we have to sort through the sql scripts and figure out why its not working. I wanted use ruby active directory to pull out a random sample of data from the database, write it to a .csv, and use R to calculate the similarity scores instead of pg_trgm. I think the stringdist package runs it in C.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?

```
library(textcat)

?textcat_xdist
# Compute cross-distances between collections of n-gram profiles.

round(textcat_xdist(
  list(
       text1="hello there",
       text2="why hello there",
       text3="totally different"
       ),
     method="cosine"),
3)

#      text1 text2 text3
#text1 0.000 0.078 0.731
#text2 0.078 0.000 0.739
#text3 0.731 0.739 0.000
```

Comment: I think the method="cosine" might be what I am looking for. Does anyone know if stringdist(string 1, string 2, method="cosine",q = 3) is similar to pg_trgm?